# Comparing two lists and assign into new list of objects

Tags: java, list, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have a one list which contains objects of class Employee and other list contains objects of class Departments like below:-

```
Class Employee {
String emolpyee_id;
String employee_Name;
}
Class Dapartment {
String emolpyee_id;
String employee_Department;
}

List<Employee> empl =  = new ArrayList<>();
List<Dapartment> depart =  = new ArrayList<>();

Employee e1 = new Employee("12","Testing");
Employee e2 = new Employee("16","TestingOthers");

Dapartment d1 = new Dapartment("12","IT");
Dapartment d2 = new Dapartment("12","Networking");
Dapartment d3 = new Dapartment("12","Financing");
Dapartment d4 = new Dapartment("16","IT");
Dapartment d5 = new Dapartment("16","Networking");

empl.add(e1);
empl.add(e2);

depart.add(d1);
depart.add(d2);
depart.add(d3);
depart.add(d4);
depart.add(d5);

Class ExpectedResult {
String emolpyee_id;
String employee_Name;
List<String> employee_Department;
}

List<ExpectedResult> expResult = {{"12","Testing",{"IT","Networking","Financing"}} ,{"16","TestingOthers",{"IT","Networking"}}}
```

I know we can perform this using normal for loop but I want to achive this output using lambda and stream of java 8.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to tech you programming. If you are new to Java 8, why don’t you read a tutorial or a book?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First stream the `List<Department>` into `Map<String,List<String>>` using groupingBy, which is map of employee id as key and value is list of departments

```
Map<String, List<String>> groupby = depart.stream().
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Department::getEmolpyee_id, Collectors.mapping(Department::getEmployee_Department, Collectors.toList())));
```

And then for every object in `List<Employee>` get the Departments from `Map`

```
List<ExpectedResult> expected = empl.stream().
            map(emp-> new ExpectedResult(emp.getEmolpyee_id(),emp.getEmployee_Name(),groupby.get(emp.getEmolpyee_id()))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note** you might get null for `List<String> employee_Department;` in `ExpectedResult` if groupby `Map` doesn't contain employee id and value

**Side Note :**  `class` is lowercase `Class` is wrong, and Department spelling correction

Comment: Thank you for your reply..It really saved my time..Thanks a lot again...